# How to run sudo visudo in a Dockerfile?

Tags: dockerfile, centos, sudo, amazon-linux, visudo

I am creating a `Dockerfile` using the `centos:7` base image.
I need to edit the file at `etc/sudoers` and append `NOPASSWD` privileges to it for a new `consul` user and some groups.

I have looked up in forums that its better to use `sudo visudo` while editing the `sudoers` file instead of using `cat`? However, I am still a beginner and any pointers regarding how that can be written in a `Dockerfile` would be helpful.